# Rotate and displace a line such that it fits another line

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

I have two lists:

```
list1 = {{0., 7.}, {-0.0701898, 7.01875}, {-0.140755, 7.03679}, {-0.211687, 
  7.05412}, {-0.28298, 7.07073}, {-0.354627, 7.08663}, {-0.426619, 
  7.10179}, {-0.498951, 7.11622}, {-0.571613, 7.12991}, {-0.644599, 
  7.14286}, {-0.717901, 7.15506}, {-0.791511, 7.16651}, {-0.865421, 
  7.1772}, {-0.939625, 7.18712}, {-1.01411, 7.19628}, {-1.08888, 
  7.20466}, {-1.16391, 7.21227}, {-1.23921, 7.21909}, {-1.31475, 
  7.22513}, {-1.39054, 7.23037}, {-1.46657, 7.23482}, {-1.54283, 
  7.23848}, {-1.6193, 7.24132}, {-1.69599, 7.24336}, {-1.77287, 
  7.24459}, {-1.84995, 7.24501}, {-1.92722, 7.2446}, {-2.00466, 
  7.24338}, {-2.08227, 7.24132}, {-2.16004, 7.23844}, {-2.23796, 
  7.23472}, {-2.31602, 7.23017}, {-2.39421, 7.22478}, {-2.47253, 
  7.21854}, {-2.55096, 7.21146}, {-2.62949, 7.20353}, {-2.70813, 
  7.19475}, {-2.78684, 7.18512}, {-2.86564, 7.17463}, {-2.9445, 
  7.16328}, {-3.02342, 7.15107}, {-3.10239, 7.13799}, {-3.1814, 
  7.12405}, {-3.26045, 7.10924}, {-3.33951, 7.09356}, {-3.41858, 
  7.07701}, {-3.49766, 7.05958}, {-3.57673, 7.04128}, {-3.65578, 
  7.0221}, {-3.73481, 7.00204}, {-3.8138, 6.98111}, {-3.89274, 
  6.95929}, {-3.97163, 6.93659}, {-4.05045, 6.913}, {-4.12919, 
  6.88854}, {-4.20785, 6.86318}, {-4.28642, 6.83694}, {-4.36488, 
  6.80982}, {-4.44322, 6.7818}, {-4.52144, 6.7529}, {-4.59953, 
  6.72311}, {-4.67747, 6.69244}, {-4.75526, 6.66087}, {-4.83288, 
  6.62842}, {-4.91033, 6.59508}, {-4.98759, 6.56085}, {-5.06466, 
  6.52574}, {-5.14152, 6.48973}, {-5.21817, 6.45285}, {-5.29459, 
  6.41507}, {-5.37078, 6.37641}, {-5.44672, 6.33687}, {-5.52241, 
  6.29645}, {-5.59784, 6.25514}, {-5.67298, 6.21295}, {-5.74785, 
  6.16989}, {-5.82241, 6.12595}, {-5.89668, 6.08113}, {-5.97062, 
  6.03544}, {-6.04425, 5.98887}, {-6.11753, 5.94144}, {-6.19047, 
  5.89313}, {-6.26306, 5.84396}, {-6.33528, 5.79393}, {-6.40712, 
  5.74304}, {-6.47858, 5.69129}, {-6.54964, 5.63868}, {-6.62029, 
  5.58522}, {-6.69053, 5.5309}, {-6.76035, 5.47574}, {-6.82973, 
  5.41974}, {-6.89866, 5.36289}, {-6.96714, 5.30521}, {-7.03515, 
  5.24669}, {-7.10269, 5.18734}, {-7.16974, 5.12717}, {-7.2363, 
  5.06617}, {-7.30235, 5.00435}, {-7.36789, 4.94172}, {-7.43291, 
  4.87827}, {-7.49739, 4.81402}, {-7.56133, 4.74896}, {-7.62471, 
  4.68311}, {-7.68753, 4.61646}, {-7.74978, 4.54902}, {-7.81145, 
  4.4808}, {-7.87253, 4.4118}, {-7.93301, 4.34203}, {-7.99287, 
  4.27148}, {-8.05212, 4.20017}, {-8.11074, 4.12811}, {-8.16872, 
  4.05529}, {-8.22606, 3.98172}, {-8.28273, 3.90741}, {-8.33875, 
  3.83236}, {-8.39409, 3.75659}, {-8.44874, 3.68009}, {-8.5027, 
  3.60287}, {-8.55597, 3.52494}, {-8.60852, 3.4463}, {-8.66035, 
  3.36697}, {-8.71145, 3.28694}, {-8.76182, 3.20622}, {-8.81145, 
  3.12483}, {-8.86032, 3.04276}, {-8.90843, 2.96003}, {-8.95576, 
  2.87664}, {-9.00232, 2.7926}, {-9.0481, 2.70792}, {-9.09307, 
  2.62259}, {-9.13725, 2.53664}, {-9.18061, 2.45007}, {-9.22315, 
  2.36288}, {-9.26487, 2.27509}, {-9.30574, 2.1867}, {-9.34578, 
  2.09771}, {-9.38497, 2.00815}, {-9.42329, 1.91801}, {-9.46075, 
  1.8273}, {-9.49734, 1.73604}, {-9.53305, 1.64423}, {-9.56786, 
  1.55188}, {-9.60179, 1.45899}, {-9.63481, 1.36558}, {-9.66691, 
  1.27166}, {-9.69811, 1.17723}, {-9.72838, 1.0823}, {-9.75771, 
  0.986886}, {-9.78611, 0.890993}, {-9.81357, 0.79463}, {-9.84008, 
  0.697808}, {-9.86563, 0.600534}, {-9.89021, 0.502819}, {-9.91383, 
  0.404672}, {-9.93647, 0.306104}, {-9.95813, 0.207122}, {-9.9788, 
  0.107739}, {-9.99848, 0.00796206}}
```

and:

```
list2 = {{0., 4.}, {-0.0403813, 4.038}, {-0.0815225, 4.07558}, {-0.123419, 
  4.11274}, {-0.166067, 4.14947}, {-0.209462, 4.18575}, {-0.253599, 
  4.22157}, {-0.298473, 4.25693}, {-0.344079, 4.29181}, {-0.390412, 
  4.32619}, {-0.437467, 4.36008}, {-0.485239, 4.39345}, {-0.533721, 
  4.4263}, {-0.582908, 4.45862}, {-0.632795, 4.49039}, {-0.683374, 
  4.52161}, {-0.734641, 4.55226}, {-0.786588, 4.58233}, {-0.83921, 
  4.61182}, {-0.892499, 4.6407}, {-0.94645, 4.66898}, {-1.00105, 
  4.69664}, {-1.05631, 4.72367}, {-1.1122, 4.75007}, {-1.16872, 
  4.77581}, {-1.22587, 4.80089}, {-1.28364, 4.82531}, {-1.34201, 
  4.84904}, {-1.40099, 4.87209}, {-1.46056, 4.89444}, {-1.52072, 
  4.91608}, {-1.58146, 4.937}, {-1.64276, 4.9572}, {-1.70463, 
  4.97666}, {-1.76705, 4.99538}, {-1.83001, 5.01334}, {-1.89351, 
  5.03054}, {-1.95753, 5.04696}, {-2.02207, 5.06261}, {-2.08712, 
  5.07746}, {-2.15266, 5.09152}, {-2.21869, 5.10477}, {-2.2852, 
  5.11721}, {-2.35218, 5.12882}, {-2.41962, 5.1396}, {-2.48751, 
  5.14954}, {-2.55584, 5.15864}, {-2.6246, 5.16688}, {-2.69377, 
  5.17425}, {-2.76336, 5.18076}, {-2.83334, 5.18639}, {-2.90371, 
  5.19113}, {-2.97445, 5.19499}, {-3.04556, 5.19794}, {-3.11703, 
  5.19999}, {-3.18883, 5.20112}, {-3.26097, 5.20134}, {-3.33344, 
  5.20062}, {-3.40621, 5.19898}, {-3.47928, 5.1964}, {-3.55264, 
  5.19287}, {-3.62627, 5.1884}, {-3.70016, 5.18296}, {-3.77431, 
  5.17657}, {-3.8487, 5.1692}, {-3.92331, 5.16087}, {-3.99814, 
  5.15155}, {-4.07318, 5.14125}, {-4.1484, 5.12996}, {-4.22381, 
  5.11768}, {-4.29938, 5.10441}, {-4.37511, 5.09013}, {-4.45098, 
  5.07484}, {-4.52697, 5.05854}, {-4.60309, 5.04122}, {-4.67931, 
  5.02289}, {-4.75562, 5.00353}, {-4.832, 4.98315}, {-4.90845, 
  4.96174}, {-4.98496, 4.93929}, {-5.0615, 4.91581}, {-5.13807, 
  4.89128}, {-5.21466, 4.86572}, {-5.29124, 4.83911}, {-5.36781, 
  4.81145}, {-5.44435, 4.78274}, {-5.52085, 4.75298}, {-5.5973, 
  4.72216}, {-5.67368, 4.69029}, {-5.74998, 4.65737}, {-5.82619, 
  4.62338}, {-5.90229, 4.58833}, {-5.97826, 4.55222}, {-6.05411, 
  4.51504}, {-6.1298, 4.47681}, {-6.20533, 4.4375}, {-6.28068, 
  4.39714}, {-6.35585, 4.3557}, {-6.43081, 4.31321}, {-6.50555, 
  4.26964}, {-6.58007, 4.22501}, {-6.65433, 4.17932}, {-6.72834, 
  4.13256}, {-6.80208, 4.08473}, {-6.87552, 4.03584}, {-6.94867, 
  3.98589}, {-7.0215, 3.93488}, {-7.09401, 3.88281}, {-7.16617, 
  3.82968}, {-7.23797, 3.7755}, {-7.30941, 3.72025}, {-7.38046, 
  3.66396}, {-7.45111, 3.60662}, {-7.52135, 3.54822}, {-7.59116, 
  3.48878}, {-7.66053, 3.4283}, {-7.72945, 3.36678}, {-7.7979, 
  3.30422}, {-7.86587, 3.24063}, {-7.93334, 3.17601}, {-8.00031, 
  3.11036}, {-8.06675, 3.04368}, {-8.13265, 2.97599}, {-8.19801, 
  2.90728}, {-8.2628, 2.83757}, {-8.32701, 2.76684}, {-8.39063, 
  2.69512}, {-8.45364, 2.62239}, {-8.51603, 2.54868}, {-8.57779, 
  2.47398}, {-8.63891, 2.3983}, {-8.69937, 2.32164}, {-8.75915, 
  2.24401}, {-8.81825, 2.16542}, {-8.87664, 2.08586}, {-8.93433, 
  2.00536}, {-8.99129, 1.92391}, {-9.04751, 1.84152}, {-9.10297, 
  1.7582}, {-9.15767, 1.67395}, {-9.2116, 1.58879}, {-9.26473, 
  1.50271}, {-9.31705, 1.41572}, {-9.36857, 1.32785}, {-9.41925, 
  1.23908}, {-9.46908, 1.14943}, {-9.51807, 1.0589}, {-9.56618, 
  0.967515}, {-9.61342, 0.87527}, {-9.65977, 0.782176}, {-9.70521, 
  0.688243}, {-9.74973, 0.593479}, {-9.79332, 0.497893}, {-9.83598, 
  0.401495}, {-9.87768, 0.304292}, {-9.91842, 0.206296}, {-9.95818, 
  0.107516}, {-9.99696, 0.00796084}}
```

Now I can plot them on a graph:

```
ListPlot[{list1,list2},Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Now the question is:

I would like to move the yellow line in such a way that it resembles as much as possible the blue line. I don't want to distort the line, just move it in x-y direction or rotate it.

In the end I would like to have a program that automatically figures out the best x and y mouvement and best rotation about a point (the program should also find that point and the angle) such that the the yellow line fits as good as possible above the blue line.

How can I do that ?

EDIT:

Here are some starting hints based on comments:

```
{err,transfo} = 
 FindGeometricTransform[list1, list2, 
  TransformationClass -> "Rigid"];
```

Then to visualize:

```
ListPlot[{list1,list2,transfo[list2],Joined->True]
```

[image]

Now... How do I get the displacment info in x and in y and the rotation info that was needed to do the geometric

Comment: Try `FindGeometricTransform[]` with the setting `TransformationClass -> "Rigid"`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks a lot, I will have a look at this fucntion.

Comment: @J.M. Okay,so I tried it: FindGeometricTransform[list1, list2, 
 TransformationClass -> "Rigid"] ... It seems to find a homogenous transformation matrix, but how do I visualize the result ?

Comment: With `Line` and `GeometricTransformation`.

Comment: @Szabolcs could you show me how to do it ?

Comment: `Graphics[{GeometricTransformation[Line[points], trafo]}]`, where you got the `trafo` from `FindGeometricTransform`.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I am sorry, but it does not work... I tried: Graphics[{GeometricTransformation[Line[list2], trafo]}]

Comment: Then try using `trafo[list2]` as the points to plot.

Comment: @Szabolcs, would you mind to try it quickly ? I am doing something wrong. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried it.  `FindGeometricTransform` gives you a transformation function.  Apply it to the second list of points.  Then they will approximately coincide with the first list of points.  I don't know why `GeometricTransformation` did not work, that is weird. But this one works. http://i.stack.imgur.com/eLHpa.png

Comment: @Szabolcs Great ! Works now !  Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Szabolcs and J.M. showed, and which you showed in your updated question, `FindGeometricTransform` can solve this problem. You then asked how to get the displacement information and rotation information. This information can be extracted using `TransformationMatrix`:

```
{err, tf} = FindGeometricTransform[list1, list2, TransformationClass -> "Rigid"];
(tm = TransformationMatrix[tf]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The 2x2 submatrix in the top left corner is the rotation transform. The two top elements in the rightmost column correspond to displacement.

```
rotation = tm[[1 ;; 2, 1 ;; 2]];
displacement = tm[[1 ;; 2, -1]];
list3 = displacement + rotation.# & /@ list2;
ListPlot[{list1, list2, list3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One problem with the `FindGeometricTransform` is that it isn't clear what it is we're minimizing. Explicitly minimizing a cost function, in this case `Norm[x]^2`, is perhaps preferable in this respect:

```
{val, sol} = NMinimize[
  Norm[{x, y} + RotationMatrix[th].# & /@ list2 - list1]^2,
  {x, y, th}
  ]
```

> `{27.0478, {x -> 0.253746, y -> 2.49059, th -> 0.263939}}`

```
tf2 = Function[{pt}, ({x, y} + RotationMatrix[th].pt /. sol)];
ListPlot[{list1, list2, list3, tf2 /@ list2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The result is similar to that of `FindGeometricTransform` and as a bonus we get the parameters directly.

Comment: Wow. Very nice ! Thanks a lot. Could you explain me what exactly: ".# & /@ list2 - list1" does ?

Comment: `{x, y} + RotationMatrix[th].# & /@ list2` is the displacement plus the rotated coordinate, for each coordinate in `list2`. To understand the subtraction just try it with two small lists like `{1,2,3} - {4,5,6}` and see what happens.

Comment: Ah, I see baiscally you are calculating the difference between the displaced and rotated points of list2, and the fixed points of list1 -> and indeed this is what you want to minimize. Is that correct ?

Comment: @DoHe I am minimizing the squared norm of that vector, yes. This is what I refer to as a cost function. It's not the only choice, but it seems to work. This particular choice is sometimes called a "least squares" optimization.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot !  :))

Comment: Quick question: How can I adapt this method, if do not have the same amount of points in both lists ?

Comment: @DoHe You need to know which points in the first list correspond to which points in the second list, and then create two lists with the same number of points in each. Otherwise it gets tricky. (As in, out of scope for this question.)

Comment: okay, I will ask a new question, I it happens to be important and I cannot solve it alone. Thanks for your help. :)